# Set import layout for xtend files in IntellJ

Tags: intellij-idea, xtend

I want the set a specific layout for imports (for example, all java.* followed be com.google.* followed by everything else) for xtend files in IntellJ. For java files I can do this by setting the import layout under "Settings->Editor->Code Style->Java->Imports->Import Layout". However I cannot find anything for xtend, i.e., I don't see anything like "Settings->Editor->Code Style->Xtend"

When I run "Optimize Imports" for xtend files they do  get formatted but in the default order and I am unable to find a way to change that default order.

Answer (score 0):

Most features in IntelliJ IDEA have to be implemented separately for each language, and a lot of features supported for Java do not exist in other language plugins. If you don't see this feature, this is because the developers of the Xtend plugin did not implement it. You can file a feature request asking them to support it.